# Replace part of a LINQ to SQL query with a reusable method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

We have introduced a new feature in our application, that affects hundreds of queries. We have to set a `bool` field to indicate if the license is valid, in a very complicated way.

I would like to create a method for returning this `bool` value, and I'd like to use it in every query. The problem is, that if I use it in the way shown below, it executes a separate query for each result.

How do I use the `Expression` in a way that it is compiled into SQL and executed as a single query?

**Original query, in need of improvement**

```
IQueryable<DeviceMinimal> devices = 
    from device in db.Devices
    where device.AccountId = accountId

    select new DeviceMinimal
    {
        Id = device.Id,
        Name = device.Name,
        LicenseIsValid = !checkForLicense || 
            device.License != null && (
                !device.License.TrialStarted
                // && 12+ licensing rules
            )
    };
```

`checkForLicense` is a `bool` that indicates that license does not need to be checked. It is used in some cases and it is necessary to be considered.

**Code, that solves the problem, but provokes a separate query for each device**

```
IQueryable<DeviceMinimal> devices = 
    from device in db.Devices
    where device.AccountId = accountId

    select new DeviceMinimal
    {
        Id = device.Id,
        Name = device.Name,
        LicenseIsValid = 
            LicenseHelper.IsLicenseValid(checkForLicense).Invoke(device)
    };
```

The method use in the query above:

```
public static Func<Device, bool> IsLicenseEnabledAndValid(bool checkForLicense)
{
    return result => !checkForLicense ||                 
        result.License != null && (
            !result.License.TrialStarted
            // && 12+ licensing rules
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `DataLoadOptions` of the `DataContext` before the query and setup them right, you should avoid the subselect. Something similar to this:

```
db.LoadOptions.LoadWith<Devices>(p => p.License);
```

Tha is the default behaviour (lazy loading of the entities). You could have for more info searching for 'linq to sql eagerloading'

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but it does not relate to my problem. Even if I use Entity.Entity.Entity in the LINQ query, this will still execute a single SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but did you try accessing the licence in the main query?
In other words something like :

```
Queryable<DeviceMinimal> devices =
   from device in db.Devices
   where device.AccountId = accountId

   select new DeviceMinimal
   {
       Id = device.Id,
       Name = device.Name,
       LicenseIsValid =
        LicenseHelper.IsLicenseEnabledAndValid(checkForLicense).Invoke(device.Licence)
   };

public static Func<License, bool> IsLicenseEnabledAndValid(bool checkForLicense)
{
    return result => !checkForLicense ||
        result != null && (
       !result.TrialStarted
        // && 12+ licensing rules
      );
}
```

If you need to access both the device and Licence in your method, you might need to change the function to be something like

```
public static Func<Device, License, bool> IsLicenseEnabledAndValid(bool checkForLicense)
{
   return (device, licence) =>  
  ...
}
```